# Store content of a file present in git to a variable in Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I have a file text.txt in GitHub, want to store it's content in Jenkins in a variable that can be later used.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

if you are willing to checkout the GitHub repo you can simply use the [ReadFile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) step in a declarative pipeline to read the file after checking out the source. Following is an example.

```
stage('read') {
        steps {
            script {
                def data = readFile(file: 'text.txt')
                println(data)
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Option 2

Get the `raw` link of the text file. For example, check [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/master/README.md). Then you can either use a [`sh` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) with a tool like `curl` or a plugin like [HTTP Request plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) to get the content. Check the following examples.

**SH with curl**

```bash
content = sh (
    script: "curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/master/README.md",
    returnStdout: true
)
```

**HTTP Request Plugin**

```
response = httpRequest 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/master/README.md'
```

Comment: Can't use declarative pipeline approach, I just have a freestyle job, where I need to pass that variable value to my docker build and publish step later in the job.
Any other way?

Comment: @ShivamMalhotra You should be able to use Env Inject plugin with a custom Groovy script for this. https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/

Comment: Yeah plugin helped by declaring variable in a properties file in git and passing it to jenkins "Using inject environment var" option did the trick.